# Replace line with space and backslash with a string containing spaces

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I want to replace the following line:

```
--memory 20g \
```

with

```
--memory 100g \
```

Actually it should replace any number after `--memory`. Following is what I have, but not able to get the expected result.

```
sed -i -E -- "s/\b--memory.*/--memroy 100g \/g"  a.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the extended regex support here (`-E`), POSIX-ly you could just do as below. The idea is you need to double-escape the meta-character `\` to make it a literal

```
sed 's/--memory \(.*\) \\/--memory 100g \\/g' a.txt
```

or if you are sure its going to be `20g` all the time, use the string directly.

```
sed 's/--memory 20g \\/--memory 100g \\/g' a.txt
```

The one advantage of using `\(.*\)` is that allows you to replace anything that could occur in that place. The `.*` is a greedy expression to match anything and in POSIX `sed` (Basic Regular Expressions) you need to escape the captured group as `\(.*\)` whereas if you do the same with the `-E` flag enabled (on GNU/FreeBSD `sed`) you could just do `(.*)`. Also use regex anchors `^`, `$` if you want to match the exact line and not to let `sed` substitute text in places that you don't need. The same operation with ERE

```
sed -E 's/--memory (.*) \\/--memory 100g \\/g' file
```

Comment: Thanks Inian... Works fine now!

Comment: @Inian: Can you please explain the part: `\(.*\)` please in your given answer.

Comment: @User123: Is that helpful for you?

Comment: It's just @jww up to his usual wacky tricks of downvoting every answer to questions he doesn't like.

Comment: @EdMorton : Not this time Ed, I’ve flagged with the meta post in he question. The mods will have a look at his behaviour. Thanks for the complement Ed. It’s high time someone warned him of his behaviour

Comment: @Inian: yes, understood.Thanks.