# Search every nth line pattern in a large file and prefix them for then next x range of lines

Tags: python, linux, bash, awk, sed

For eg

I have a huge file with the pattern below. The search pattern is the date and i have to prefix the date for the next n number of rows. The date pattern is at the exact nth repetitive line and the next few lines are also a fixed number.

```
date 1  
line 1  
line 2  
line 3  
date 2  
line 4  
line 5  
line 6  
date 3  
line 7  
line 8  
line 9
```

The above pattern should be transformed to look like below

```
date 1 line 1  
date 1 line 2  
date 1 line 3  
date 2 line 4  
date 2 line 5  
date 2 line 6  
date 3 line 7  
date 3 line 8  
date 3 line 9
```

Is there a simple command using sed/awk which would do this or should i go ahead and write a bash/python script ?

Comment: @jww downvoted the question and all answers again so once again I'm upvoting them all to compensate.

Comment: Shouldn't such behavior be reported to a moderator?

Answer (score 2):

With awk:

```
awk -v pattern="date" '$0~pattern{p=$0;next}{print p,$0}' file
```

Change the `pattern` variable to whatever matches your file.

Comment: @DOWNVOTER, please explain WHY?

Comment: Any time you see bulk downvoting like this you can be sure it was @jww. I'm upvoting all answers and the question again to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way in Python:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('date'):
            date = line
            continue
        print(date, line)
```

**Output**:

```
date 1 line 1
date 1 line 2
date 1 line 3
date 2 line 4
date 2 line 5
date 2 line 6
date 3 line 7
date 3 line 8
date 3 line 9
```

Comment: Downvoter, please leave a comment.

Comment: Any time you see bulk downvoting like this you can be sure it was @jww. I'm upvoting all answers and the question again to compensate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/608639/jww. Any time he doesn't like something about a question he downvotes everyone who answered it, eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635955/sed-to-split-based-on-quotes-handling-comma-within-quotes-along-with-data-withou#comment88310460_50635955, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635955/sed-to-split-based-on-quotes-handling-comma-within-quotes-along-with-data-withou#comment88310460_50635955, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559897/replace-line-with-space-and-backslash-with-a-string-containing-spaces/50559951#comment88145649_50559951

Answer (score 0):

A simple python scrip that could do this:

```
k=nth_rep
line_k=0
with open("the_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if (line_k % k == 0):
            date_line = str(line)
            line = '\n'
        else:
            line = line + " " + date_line
        line_k= line_k + 1
```

not tested

Answer (score 0):

There is awk solution:

```
awk '{if ($1 == "date") a_date = $0} { if ($1 == "line") print a_date $0}'
```

Explenation:
 if line first column equals `date` store this line.
 if line first column equals `line` print stored value and this line.